# Is PouchDB with LevelDB adapter supposed to create a local file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, pouchdb

This leaflet example ([Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached)) is using an "idb" adapter and for electron/node it looks like I want to use a "leveldb" adapter. So I followed the instructions here: [PouchDB in Node.js](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html)

> In Node.js, the adapter situation is much simpler than in browsers. By
>   default, if you create a PouchDB like this one:
>
> var pouch = new PouchDB('./path/to/db');
>
> then a LevelDB-based database will be created in the directory
>   ./path/to/db. The LevelDB implementation uses LevelDOWN.

In my "main.js" (Electron entry point) I create a db like this:

```
var dbPath = path.join(__dirname, 'main-db');
var myDB = new PouchDB(dbPath);
console.log('myDB', myDB.adapter);
```

And though the adapter type is reported as "leveldb" it does not show up on disk.

**Question:** Where is the database created? I've looked in my app directory, in the node_modules/pouchdb directory. I've even looked for "hidden files" (this is on OSX). What gives? If I dump the db instance to the console, it looks like it was created (in memory). Am I "doing it wrong"?

Comment: Yes, it should create local folders / files. What path does `console.log(dbPath )` give you?

Comment: @Marc – thanks. Yes, it seems (at least partly) a path issue. I was able to create the db in my `main.js` and it appeared on disk. Still no success with it in my `index.html`

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had a couple of things going wrong.

1. The path I was using was incorrect. Even though I was trying to create the pouchDB instance from a Javascript file attached to an index.html file *inside* my app folder, this path did not work: `'./db/todo-db'`. I was able to create the db instance using this path: `'./app/db/todo-db'`.

   This seems odd to me and I don't understand it. The `__dirname` reports that my JS context was `'./path/to/app/` – so I am already *inside* the app folder.
2. I was getting an error message about a mismatch between the NODE version which levelDB (the adapter I was requesting) was compiled for. I was able to solve this by using [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) in a postinstall call:

In my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-rebuild",
   etc.
  }
```