# Spark connectivity with CouchDB and LevelDB

Tags: apache-spark, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, leveldb

I am new to Hyperledger Blockchain. I want to connect Apache Spark with CouchDB and LevelDB so that I can process and analyze Blockchain data. How can I do that ? Can someone give a step by step way?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give a step-by-step way, but there is something you might be interested in:

[PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html) is based on CouchDB and is using LevelDB as one of its adapters. Therefore, PouchDB might help you with processing and analyzing blockchain data. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43129478/3405291) which is using `LevelBD` adapter with PouchDB.